# Exporting Visualforce page to Microsoft Word with nested lists

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, pdf

I have a legal document in Salesforce that I am displaying as a pdf. I need to also be able to download it as a Word document. I've got everything working except nested lists. Ideally I want them to look like this:

```
1. HEADING
  1.1 (text)
  1.2 (text)
    1.2.1 (text)
    1.2.2 (text)
```

This is the closest I've been able to replicate this **when rendering as a PDF**. It's not ideal but it's acceptable enough and I'm tired of wrestling with it:
[image: PDF screenshot]

---

**However, this is what it does when I download as an MS Word file. Notice how it's resetting the counter for every nested list, and it's missing the "1.1, 1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2" etc..:**
[image: MS Word screenshot]

**How do I get it to export to Microsoft word as a custom-formatted "multilevel list" instead of what I'm getting here?**

Here are the important bits of my code.

**Visualforce:**

```
<ol class="nested">
    <li><span class="heading6">Customer’s Obligations</span>

    <ol class="nested">
        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Access to the FlightStats Service.</span> Customer shall access the FlightStats Service either by posting and maintaining at the Customer site software to the FlightStats Service or by providing other direct means for accessing the FlightStats Service (either of such means of access, the “FlightStats Link”).  All costs associated with Customer’s compliance with <u>Schedule C</u> hereto and the implementation and maintenance of the FlightStats Link on the Customer site shall be the sole responsibility of Customer.  FlightStats shall have the right to review and certify Customer’s implementation of any FlightStats Link, and to prevent unauthorized access to the FlightStats Service, prior to Customer placing the FlightStats Service into production. </li>

        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Customer Support Services.</span>  Customer shall be solely responsible for providing customer support services related to the Customer site and any related network.  Customer shall be solely responsible for all costs incurred in providing its customer support services. </li>

        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Customer Support Services.</span>  Customer shall be solely responsible for providing customer support services related to the Customer site and any related network.  Customer shall be solely responsible for all costs incurred in providing its customer support services.</li>              
    </ol>
</li>

<li><span class="heading6">FlightStats’s Obligations</span>

    <ol class="nested">
        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Providing Service.</span> FlightStats shall provide to Customer the FlightStats Service through the FlightStats Link to allow Customer Users the right to access and use the FlightStats Service.  The FlightStats Service shall be provided in accordance with the service and support standards set forth in Schedule C.</li>

        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Deprecation of a FlightStats Service.</span> FlightStats shall provide a minimum 90 days notice when deprecating an older version of a FlightStats Service.  Upon deprecation, the older service will be minimally supported, and the Service Availability and Incident Response sections of Schedule C will be terminated as it relates to the deprecated service.</li>

        <li><br/>
        <span class="heading5">Retirement of a FlightStats Service.</span> FlightStats shall make best efforts to provide a minimum 180 days notice when retiring a FlightStats Service.  Upon retirement, the service will be fully removed.  All costs associated with Customer’s migration to a different service shall be the sole responsibility of the Customer.</li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

**CSS/header stuff** (I can't seem use an external stylesheet):

```
<apex:page controller="pdfContractDownloadDocxController" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false" cache="true" contentType="application/ms-Word#{!$CurrentPage.parameters.contractType} - {!$CurrentPage.parameters.companyName}.doc" >

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" charset="utf-8" />

<style type="text/css" media="print">
/* BOTH PDF AND MS WORD */
/* GENERAL STYLING */
@page {
    size: letter;
    margin: 0.5in;
}
.heading5 {
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
.heading6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: capitalize; 
    font-variant: small-caps; 
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

/* NESTED LISTS */
ol.nested { 
    counter-reset: item; 
    list-style: decimal;
    margin-left: 0em;
}
ol.nested li {
    display: block; 
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: left;  
}
ol.nested li:before { 
    content: counters(item, ".") " "; 
    counter-increment: item; 
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
}

</style> 
</head>
```

Comment: I can tell you one debugging technique save the PDF to doc or convert it  to doc then save the doc as html using word and compare the HTML hope you will notice the difference

Comment: That's a good thought. I just tried that using a free online converter (PDF to DOC file). What I ended up with looks perfect, however if I look carefully I notice it's not using a multilevel list at all. It's literally just the straight text values ("1", "1.1", etc..). In other words, I am able to delete or edit the numbers as if they are like any other text, and the rest of the numbers in the list are not affected. So no CSS is being used.
This would be fine with me, but I don't know of a way to do this in code (convert a css-style ordered list to straight text).